# Don't see imported objects in All Tabs screen

Tags: deployment, sobject, tab

I moved a bunch of objects (and their dependencies) from one sandbox to another using the Inbound/Outbound Sets feature - it went well.

However, I don't see any of those objects in the All Tabs screen.  I'd like to add one of those imported objects to the list of tabs.

Am I missing some intermediary step?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a tab for custom objects.

> Setup->Create->Tabs

If you have the tabs already created in your other sandbox you could also move those over using an outbound Change Set or the Migration Tool.

1. Create a new OutBound Change Set
2. Under "Change Set Components" click "Add"
3. Select the tabs dropdown and select the appropriate tabs.
4. Deploy the changeset

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the custom object tab in the change set? If not, you'd need to create tab by going to Setup > Create > Tabs.